# Is a counterspell ineffective against the wrong spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, counterspelling

I had this idea in my campaign to rob a magic store. Logically, it makes sense that the owner of said store knows *counterspell*.  What I plan to do is to take out the components of *fireball* but not cast *fireball*. Simultaneously, I'll take out the components for *major image*, concealing them, and create a "fireball", then run out with whatever stolen goods I have.

Since the spell the shop owner is countering isn't *fireball*, would this casting of *counterspell* be ineffective?

Comment: A whole host of related questions: "[Can you counterspell a spell if you don't know who's casting it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160341)", "[What do I know, when deciding whether to cast Counterspell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46830)", "[Are there any rules for identifying what spell an opponent is casting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/149874)", 
and "[What happens if you cast Counterspell on a creature that is not casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115246)".

Comment: How do you intend to cast one spell while simultaneously pretending to cast another when they both require an action?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## The shopkeeper's *counterspell* works fine.

*Counterspell* is an "attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of casting a spell." Nowhere does *counterspell* say that the counter-caster needs to know what spell is being cast--in my experience they usually don't!

What does *counterspell* require? Well, the casting time is a reaction whose trigger is a creature within 60' casting a spell. It sounds from your description like you're a creature; I assume from the "cast and run out" description that the shop's smaller than 60', so it sounds like the trigger for the reaction is satisfied. Thus the shopkeeper can counter your *major image*, even if they thought is was a *fireball* you were intending.

(Where it seems like you might have room to head-fake the store owner like this would be if you *pretended* to cast *fireball*--perhaps some kind of Performance check?--while actually casting something lower-level in the hopes that the shopkeeper would blow their spell slot, and *then* drop your fireball. Of course, [you really shouldn't drop a *fireball* in the middle of a store](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131825/23970).)